# I need help plotting using smooth.spline in r

Tags: r, spline

I am using spline.smooth in r and need some help. Here are my codes:

```
my_df_1 <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2020/1/15"), by = "day", length.out = 100),
                      rate = runif(100, min=0, max=0.7),
                      count=sample(2:50, 100, replace = TRUE))

fit <- smooth.spline(my_df_1$date, my_df_1$rate)
plot(my_df_1$date, my_df_1$rate)
lines(fit)
```

First, I want to change the size of points on plot using column count. Second, is there a way to plot smooth spline in ggplot? Third, how can I format my x-axis for the date. I want to have a day and month in the x-axis. Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
my_df_1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = rate)) +
  geom_smooth() +
  geom_point(aes(size = count)) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d-%B")
```

Comment: smooth.spline I can adjust the smoothness. I am not sure how i can do it with geom_smooth()

Comment: There are a bunch of options to control how the smoothing works but you probably want to start by playing with span: `geom_smooth(span = .1)`.